# Android app crashes because fragments become null

Tags: android, crash

I am making an app, and whenever I either wait a long time to use the app since it has been in the background or use a Task Killer (I don't actually use Task Killers, they are just handy for bringing up bugs that would otherwise be hard to replicate) then when I press a button on my app, it crashes, and I have found through logcat it is because tempmainfrag is returning as null in the following code when used in saveButtonClicked and deleteButtonClicked methods:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity 
        implements MainListFragment.OnListSelectedListener {

    MainListFragment tempmainfrag;
    InfoFragment infofrag;
    int mainPosition = -1;
    MenuItem menuItemAdd;   //plus button in ActionBar/options menu
    boolean menucreated = false;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mainlayout);

        // Check whether the activity is using the layout version with
        // the fragment_container FrameLayout. If so, we must add the first fragment
        if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) { //meaning, if using phone version

            // However, if we're being restored from a previous state,
            // then we don't need to do anything and should return or else
            // we could end up with overlapping fragments.
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                return;
            }



            // Create an instance of MainListFragment
            tempmainfrag = new MainListFragment();  //made a context parameter to pass the context

            // In case this activity was started with special instructions from an Intent,
            // pass the Intent's extras to the fragment as arguments
            tempmainfrag.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());



            // Add the fragment to the 'fragment_container' FrameLayout
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container, tempmainfrag).commit();

            Log.i("mydebug","TEMPMAINFRAG: " + tempmainfrag);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {       
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart()
    {

        Log.i("mydebug","1");
        if(menuItemAdd != null)     
            menuItemAdd.setVisible(true);   //turns on menu item 'add'

        super.onStart();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        menuItemAdd = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_add);
        menucreated = true;

        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_add:     //NEED TO IMPLEMENT: MAKES ICON PRESS FOR BACK GO BACK
                // Create fragment
                infofrag = new InfoFragment(menuItemAdd);
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putBoolean(infofrag.ARG_NEW, true);

                infofrag.setArguments(args);

                FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
                // and add the transaction to the back stack so the user can navigate back
                transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, infofrag);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);

                // Commit the transaction
                transaction.commit();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    public void onItemSelected(int position, String schedulename, String[] ampm, boolean[] days, int[] times, boolean vibrate) {
        // The user selected a list item

        //////////////////////////////TWO PANE LAYOUT STUFF///////////////////////////////////
        // Capture the article fragment from the activity layout
//        InfoFragment articleFrag = (InfoFragment)
//                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.article_fragment);  //article_fragment exists in layout-large
//
//        if (articleFrag != null) {
//            // If article frag is available, we're in two-pane layout...
//
//            // Call a method in the ArticleFragment to update its content
//            articleFrag.updateArticleView(position);
//
//        } else {
            // phone layout - swap frags

            mainPosition = position;

            // Create fragment and give it an argument for the selected article
            infofrag = new InfoFragment(menuItemAdd);
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(infofrag.ARG_POSITION, position);

            //new stuff to add info
            args.putString(infofrag.ARG_NAME, schedulename);    
            args.putBooleanArray(infofrag.ARG_DAYS, days);
            args.putIntArray(infofrag.ARG_TIMES, times);
            args.putBoolean(infofrag.ARG_VIBRATE, vibrate); 
            args.putStringArray(infofrag.ARG_AMPM, ampm);
            args.putBoolean(infofrag.ARG_NEW, false);

            infofrag.setArguments(args);
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
            // and add the transaction to the back stack so the user can navigate back
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, infofrag);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);

            // Commit the transaction
            transaction.commit();

    }

    public void saveButtonClicked(View view) {  //pass the click to the mainlistfragment
//      MainListFragment tempmainfrag2 = (MainListFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().
//                findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);

        Log.i("mydebug","TEMPMAINFRAG: " + tempmainfrag);
        if(!infofrag.newsched)  //if existing schedule, so save
        {
            Log.i("mydebug","Saving schedule...");
            boolean redo = false;       //is set true every time info isnt correct when trying to save schedule
            //create toast
            Toast toast;

            //get title
            EditText titletext = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.titletext);

            //get checkboxes
            CheckBox check1 = (CheckBox)this.findViewById(R.id.monbox); //recreate checkboxes from view in activity (doesnt extend Activity 
            CheckBox check2 = (CheckBox)this.findViewById(R.id.tuebox); //so use getActivity())
            CheckBox check3 = (CheckBox)this.findViewById(R.id.wedbox);
            CheckBox check4 = (CheckBox)this.findViewById(R.id.thubox);
            CheckBox check5 = (CheckBox)this.findViewById(R.id.fribox);
            CheckBox check6 = (CheckBox)this.findViewById(R.id.satbox);
            CheckBox check7 = (CheckBox)this.findViewById(R.id.sunbox);
            CheckBox vibratebox = (CheckBox)this.findViewById(R.id.vibratecheckbox);

            //get times
            TimePicker startpicker = (TimePicker)this.findViewById(R.id.starttimepicker);
            TimePicker stoppicker = (TimePicker)this.findViewById(R.id.stoptimepicker);

            //check for input errors
            if(titletext.getText().toString().length() == 0) //if title is empty
            {
                redo = true;
                toast = Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Enter an event name", 4);
                toast.show();

                //some sick-ass shake animations!!!
                Animation shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(titletext.getContext(), R.anim.shake_big);
                this.findViewById(R.id.titletext).startAnimation(shake);
            }
            else if((!check1.isChecked()) && (!check2.isChecked()) && (!check3.isChecked()) && 
                    (!check4.isChecked()) && (!check5.isChecked()) && (!check6.isChecked()) && 
                    (!check7.isChecked()))  //if all checkboxes arent checked
            {
                redo = true;
                toast = Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "At least one day of week must be checked", 4);
                toast.show();

                //more sick-ass shake animations!!!
                Animation shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(titletext.getContext(), R.anim.shake_small);
                this.findViewById(R.id.checkboxes).startAnimation(shake);
                this.findViewById(R.id.daysofweek).startAnimation(shake);
                this.findViewById(R.id.frequencytext).startAnimation(shake);
            }

            if(!redo)   //if all info is fine
            {
                //check to see if time goes into next day
                if((startpicker.getCurrentHour() > stoppicker.getCurrentHour())||
                        ((startpicker.getCurrentHour() == stoppicker.getCurrentHour())
                                && (startpicker.getCurrentMinute() >= stoppicker.getCurrentMinute())))
                {
                    toast = Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Note: Stop time is earlier than start time, so this schedule stops at next day", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.show();
                }

                toast = Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Schedule saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();

                //changing old schedule to new one
                boolean[] tempdays = {check1.isChecked(), check2.isChecked(), check3.isChecked(), check4.isChecked(), 
                        check5.isChecked(), check6.isChecked(), check7.isChecked()};

                Log.i("mydebug","Time info read from counters: Start hour: " + startpicker.getCurrentHour() + "\nStop hour: " + stoppicker.getCurrentHour());

                tempmainfrag.mainObjectList.changeSchedule(mainPosition, titletext.getText().toString(), tempdays, vibratebox.isChecked(), 
                        startpicker.getCurrentHour(), startpicker.getCurrentMinute(), stoppicker.getCurrentHour(), stoppicker.getCurrentMinute());

                //used to hide keyboard in case its still open when displaying list
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)this.getSystemService(
                          Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(titletext.getWindowToken(), 0);

                this.onBackPressed();   //replicates backpress to go back to list
            }
        }
        else        //if new schedule needs to be created
        {
            Log.i("mydebug","Creating new schedule...");
            boolean redo = false;
            //create toast
            Toast toast;

            //get title
            EditText titletext = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.titletext);

            //get checkboxes
            CheckBox check1 = (CheckBox)this.findViewById(R.id.monbox); //recreate checkboxes from view in activity (doesnt extend Activity 
            CheckBox check2 = (CheckBox)this.findViewById(R.id.tuebox); //so use getActivity())
            CheckBox check3 = (CheckBox)this.findViewById(R.id.wedbox);
            CheckBox check4 = (CheckBox)this.findViewById(R.id.thubox);
            CheckBox check5 = (CheckBox)this.findViewById(R.id.fribox);
            CheckBox check6 = (CheckBox)this.findViewById(R.id.satbox);
            CheckBox check7 = (CheckBox)this.findViewById(R.id.sunbox);
            CheckBox vibratebox = (CheckBox)this.findViewById(R.id.vibratecheckbox);

            //get times
            TimePicker startpicker = (TimePicker)this.findViewById(R.id.starttimepicker);
            TimePicker stoppicker = (TimePicker)this.findViewById(R.id.stoptimepicker);

            EditText temppp = titletext;
            //check for input errors
            if(titletext.getText().toString().length() == 0) //if title is empty
            {
                redo = true;
                toast = Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Enter an event name", 4);
                toast.show();

                //some sick-ass shake animations!!!
                Animation shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(titletext.getContext(), R.anim.shake_big);
                this.findViewById(R.id.titletext).startAnimation(shake);
            }
            else if((!check1.isChecked()) && (!check2.isChecked()) && (!check3.isChecked()) && 
                    (!check4.isChecked()) && (!check5.isChecked()) && (!check6.isChecked()) && 
                    (!check7.isChecked()))  //if all checkboxes arent checked
            {
                redo = true;
                toast = Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "At least one day of week must be checked", 4);
                toast.show();

                //more sick-ass shake animations!!!
                Animation shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(titletext.getContext(), R.anim.shake_small);
                this.findViewById(R.id.checkboxes).startAnimation(shake);
                this.findViewById(R.id.daysofweek).startAnimation(shake);
                this.findViewById(R.id.frequencytext).startAnimation(shake);
            }

            if(!redo)   //if all info is fine
            {
                //check to see if time goes into next day
                if((startpicker.getCurrentHour() > stoppicker.getCurrentHour())||
                        ((startpicker.getCurrentHour() == stoppicker.getCurrentHour())
                                && (startpicker.getCurrentMinute() >= stoppicker.getCurrentMinute())))
                {
                    toast = Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Note: Stop time is earlier than start time, so this schedule stops at next day", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.show();
                }

                toast = Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Schedule created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();

                //changing old schedule to new one
                boolean[] tempdays = {check1.isChecked(), check2.isChecked(), check3.isChecked(), check4.isChecked(), 
                        check5.isChecked(), check6.isChecked(), check7.isChecked()};

                Log.i("mydebug","Time info read from counters: Start hour: " + startpicker.getCurrentHour() + "\nStop hour: " + stoppicker.getCurrentHour());

                tempmainfrag.mainObjectList.addSchedule(titletext.getText().toString(), tempdays, vibratebox.isChecked(), 
                        startpicker.getCurrentHour(), startpicker.getCurrentMinute(), stoppicker.getCurrentHour(), stoppicker.getCurrentMinute());

                //used to hide keyboard in case its still open when displaying list
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)this.getSystemService(
                          Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(titletext.getWindowToken(), 0);

                this.onBackPressed();   //replicates backpress to go back to list
            }
        }
    }

    public void deleteButtonClicked(View view)
    {
        //tempmainfrag = (MainListFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().
                //findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);

        if(!infofrag.newsched)  //if existing schedule, so ask to delete
        {
            //make a notification

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Delete?");
            builder.setIcon(R.drawable.trash_icon);
            builder.setMessage("Are you sure you wish to delete this schedule?")
               .setCancelable(false)
               .setPositiveButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       tempmainfrag.mainObjectList.removeSchedule(mainPosition);

                       Toast toast;
                       toast = Toast.makeText(tempmainfrag.getActivity(), "Schedule deleted", 4);
                        toast.show();

                       tempmainfrag.exit();
                   }
               })
               .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                   }
               });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }
        else    //if new schedule, so just cancel
            tempmainfrag.exit();
    }

    public void hideKeyboard()  //hides keyboard, called whenever reverting back to list
    {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
                  Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(this.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}
```

I realize it is because in onCreate, the saveinstancestate isn't null so a new fragment isn't created, so what is a better way to do this then? I tried using

```
MainListFrag tempmainfrag = (MainListFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().
                findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
```

But it was giving me errors as well.

Comment: What errors were you getting when you used findFragmentById?

Comment: It was still returning null. If I were to implement that where would I put it?

Answer (score 0):

Change the fragment transaction method to replace instead of add. This way multiple overlapping fragments wont be created and will just replace the existing one.

```
        // Add the fragment to the 'fragment_container' FrameLayout
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .**replace**(R.id.fragment_container, tempmainfrag).commit();
```

Comment: I changed it to replace and now it doesn't crash if left off on the mainlistfragment, but if I was last on the infofragment and pressed home and do the taskkiller then it crashes on restartup

Comment: What does the log say upon crash?